# Android Set Event using Alarm Manager?

Tags: android, events, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, reminders

I am trying to make a reminder event that would display a notification at a given time in my application for sake of this example I set the `Calendar` instance to one minute to the current time. This is my `appointment.java` code, this is where the instance of `Calendar` are initialized to current time + one minute for the sake of this example.

```
Calendar ctest = Calendar.getInstance();
ctest.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 1);
Intent myIntent = new Intent(Appointments.this, AlarmRec.class);
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Appointments.this, 0, myIntent,0);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, ctest.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

Then I have the following code in my `AlarmRec.class` that acts as the BroadcastReceiver.

```
public class AlarmRec extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {  
        Intent service1 = new Intent(context, MyAlarmService.class);
        context.startService(service1);
    }
}
```

Then at last in my `MyAlarmService.class` I have the following

```
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId)
{
   super.onStart(intent, startId);

   mManager = (NotificationManager) this.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(this.getApplicationContext().NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
   Intent intent1 = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);

   Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,"This is a test message!", System.currentTimeMillis());
   intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP| Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

   PendingIntent pendingNotificationIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity( this.getApplicationContext(),0, intent1,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
   notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
   notification.setLatestEventInfo(this.getApplicationContext(), "AlarmManagerDemo", "This is a test message!", pendingNotificationIntent);

   mManager.notify(0, notification);
}
```

and my `AndroidManifest` contains

```
  <service android:name=".MyAlarmService"
             android:enabled="true" />

    <receiver android:name=".AlarmRec"/>
```

the problem I am having is nothing is being displayed no notification or anything so I'm not sure if i am doing something wrong

Also if i have made mistakes in my post please bear with me if i made mistakes with my formatting in the question.

EDIT

**wow solved thanks for the help guys, got rid of broadcast receiver and just used the service although it was still not working at the end i realized i had a small typo in my android manifest**

`<service android:name=".MyAlarmService"
                 android:enabled="true" />`

**If you see I forgot to specify my package name for the service should have been myCF.MyAlarmService**

**Thanks for the help everyone I really appreciate it**

Comment: what is your problem?

Comment: no notification is displayed nothing really happens

Comment: why you use broadcast receiver here you want to start service on boot time?

Comment: ummm i want to start service anytime after an appointment is set if i set too 10 minutes from now it should give me notification and if i do 3 days from now and in that time if i have reboot my phone it should still give me notification is broadcast receiver not the best option in this case?

Comment: then you do not need broadcast recever

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,    replace your broadcast receiver class to service `

(AlarmRec.class===> MyAlarmService.class))`

```
Calendar ctest = Calendar.getInstance();
        ctest.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 1);
         Intent myIntent = new Intent(Appointments.this, MyAlarmService.class);
          pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Appointments.this, 0, myIntent,0);
         AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
```

EDIT

```
alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                System.currentTimeMillis(), 5000, pendingIntent);
```

Comment: both u and Satyaki Mukherjee had same answer but none worked :(

Comment: i have delay 5 sec (5000) it should fire every 5 sec

Comment: tried it still not working :( maybe its my emulator let me install it on my device

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the following code:

```
long currentTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
long nextUpdateTimeMillis = currentTimeMillis * DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS;
Maybe you meant for the alarm to go off in one minute:

long nextUpdateTimeMillis = currentTimeMillis + DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS;
Anyway first use:

alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 
                          System.currentTimeMillis() + 10000, 
                          5000,
                          pendingIntent);
To confirm your setup is correct, if so you need to recalculate your nextUpdateTimeMillis
```

Courtesy of Sam
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13593926/1465910

Comment: AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
   alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 
                 System.currentTimeMillis() + 10000, 
                 5000,
                 pendingIntent);


I tried that to no avail

Answer (score 0):

You need to register the broadcast in your service, similar to this one:
[register receiver in a service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4462037/register-receiver-in-a-service)

Answer (score 0):

Call the service from the Activity because no need of receiver:

```
Calendar ctest = Calendar.getInstance();
    ctest.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 1);
     Intent myIntent = new Intent(Appointments.this, MyAlarmService.class);
      pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Appointments.this, 0, myIntent,0);
     AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
      alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, ctest.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
startService(myIntent );
```

After that change your MyAlarmService.class by the following code:

```
    @Override   
    public void onCreate() 
    {   
      super.onCreate(); 

    }

    @Override   
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) 
    {   


        NotificationManager mManager = (NotificationManager) this.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(this.getApplicationContext().NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
           Intent intent1 = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(),MainActivity1.class);

           Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,"This is a test message!", System.currentTimeMillis());
           intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP| Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

           PendingIntent pendingNotificationIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity( this.getApplicationContext(),0, intent1,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
           notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
           notification.setLatestEventInfo(this.getApplicationContext(), "AlarmManagerDemo", "This is a test message!", pendingNotificationIntent);

           mManager.notify(0, notification);
        return 0;

    }
```

It will work. try this and let me know.

Comment: I see what you mean i made the changed but still nothing coming up :(

Comment: Before I give you the code I have tested it on device. So, sorry I have no idea more than that.